# SQL Regexp like pattern match on any combination of words

Tags: sql, regex, regexp-substr, regexp-like

So I'm working in the perl sql flavor with a regexp_like and need to combine two tables based on pattern matching. One item might be 'Mammogram-bilateral' the other may be 'bilateral mammogram scan'  I really need help with matching to get 9 out of 10 words matched, if that doesn't work then 8 out of 10 and so on, or the most like characters (or words) in both tables.

I really need help getting the base of this going, the rest I could clean myself. I could clean myself ( for instance 'removal of pacemaker' i need to be different from 'insertion of pacemaker', but I understand fixing that might be a big task). The problem I'm having is in getting rows like that to match on just a regexp_like(x,y,'i') type join.

Newbie to regular expressions, I have spent hours searching for help but can't find anything, sorry if I missed something

UPDATE: Okay, so I for clarification, I've currently got this running-

```
regexp_substr(x.x.concept_name,'\w+\b',1,1) = regexp_substr(y.x,'\w+\b',1,1)
AND regexp_substr (x.x,'\w+\b',1,2) = regexp_substr (x.y,'\w+\b',1,2)
AND regexp_substr (x.x,'\w+\b',1,3) = regexp_substr (x.y,'\w+\b',1,3)
and so on...
```

So that matches the first 3 words (also it just occurred to do a whitespace count as a filter, in this case if it has 3 whitespaces). i would basically need to do 1,2 = (1,1||1,2||1,3) and so on forever, some of these have over 100 whitespaces though...
so Regexp_like doesn't quite work, but i'm trying to find a `regexp_substr()` to work.

Update 2: Levenshtein distance might help for some of these, but i would need to find the shortest distance between those two, I'm not aware of a way to do that though.

update 4:

> 'Spinal Fusion' = 'Fusion of the Spine'
>       'Mammogram-bilateral' = 'bilateral mammogram scan'
>       'Echocardiogram (ECG)' = 'ECG'

update 5: I actually use regexp_ilike(x,y), but regexp_like() seems to be more common. its Vertica SQL syntax, which uses PCRE (Perl)

Comment: You have two strings? Can you provide the stuff you need to compare?

Comment: This isn't something that `REGEXP_LIKE()` can do. It just tests whether a pattern matches or not, it can't rank similarity. What you need to use is something like Levenshtein distance.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution involves out of order matching and a regex engine that supports conditionals. This matches 3 out of 5 for example. `(?s)(?:.*?(?:(?(1)(?!))(word1)|(?(2)(?!))(word2)|(?(3)(?!))(word3)|(?(4)(?!))(word4)|(?(5)(?!))(word5)|(?(1)(?!))(word1))){3}` https://regex101.com/r/z3ui93/1 Within the `word` expressions can be any type of logic that can be thought of, partials, anything.

Comment: Another alternative if the engine doesn't support conditionals, is to use look ahead assertions like this `(?s)^(?=.*?(word1))?(?=.*?(word2))?(?=.*?(word3))?(?=.*?(word4))?(?=.*?(word5))?` but the captures have to be counted after the match for not equal NULL to get a range of like 3 minimum. This extra action would also seem a step too far for regex_like.

Comment: The fact that you're using `REGEXP_LIKE` makes me think you're using an Oracle database. If that is the case the routines in the [UTL_MATCH package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_match.htm#ARPLS352) might be helpful to you.